# Load Image from web using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

new to Android dev. The app is a really simple one, click a button to load an image from online using AsyncTask and fragments, but I still can't get it not to default to a null image (the image is definitely online). The Internet permission has been set in the Manifest and the button and ImageView have been declared on the fragment_main.xml.

Any hints to what I'm missing? Android Studio hasn't picked up on any syntactical errors...

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.InputStream;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.widget.*;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;
ImageView img;
Bitmap bitmap;
ProgressDialog progress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            new getImage().execute("https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/9b/2d/f2/new-york-city.jpg");

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private class getImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {

        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(args[0]).getContent());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progress.setMessage("Loading Image ....");
        progress.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {
        super.onPostExecute(image);

        if(image != null){
            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            progress.dismiss();
        } else{
            progress.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, don't do it with async task, there are a lot of libraries that can help you.

[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) is a great image loading library, very easy to implement and works asynchronously.

All you have to do is add this dependancy:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

to your apps build.gradle file.

After that, just add this to your activity:

```
Picasso.with(this).load("https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/9b/2d/f2/new-york-city.jpg").into(img);
```

Voila, you're done!

Comment: In searching for some help with this, I did see that Picasso was a better resource. Unfortunately, I needed to get AsyncTask to work for school.

Comment: In that case, [give this a look](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/download-image-using-asynctask-in-android).